# How to select list item with dynamically generated ids - Selenium test Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem here where I am unable to locate the list items.

```
<ul id="select2-id_faculty_advisor-results" class="select2-results__options" role="tree" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
    <li id="select2-id_faculty_advisor-result-0pu4-1" class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">Alice</li>
    <li id="select2-id_faculty_advisor-result-cayw-2" class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Bob</li>
    <li id="select2-id_faculty_advisor-result-4h8e-3" class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Candy</li>
    <li id="select2-id_faculty_advisor-result-el4l-4" class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Dark</li>
</ul>
```

As seen above I'll not be able to find elements by id as the characters in between are generated dynamically. Any idea of how to locate a particular element??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the part of the id that does not change in a css selector like:
 `li[id*='faculty_advisor-result']`

You can also add extra attributes if needed, for example aria-selected like:
 `li[id*='faculty_advisor-result'][aria-selected='false']` or any other attribute.

If you don't have any specific attribute for a particular option then you could use xpath to select the element that has that option like:
 `//li[contains(@id, 'faculty_advisor-result')][text()='Alice']`
the same way you can add extra filters to narrow the results like `[@role='tree']`

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do it make collection of list by xpath "//ul[@id='select2-id_faculty_advisor-results']/li"

after that you can select them by index from the collection.